# Cannot return a True or Force value out of a variable within an if statement in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have the following checkbox who is calling a function on launch to get checked based on a value that comes in from an api (cat.term_id)

```
<input ng-checked="ifCatExcluded(cat.term_id)">
```

The function works as follows: The first bit sets the checkbox value to true and gets an array which i need to cross check the id.

```
$scope.ifCatExcluded = function(sent_id){

    var doesNotExist = true;

    arraytosearch = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("categoryListMem"));
```

The second bit creates an empty array and adds the cat.term_id to this new array to avoid re running this id later.

```
if($scope.tempArray == undefined || $scope.tempArray.indexOf(undefined) > 0) {
        $scope.tempArray = [];
    }

    if ($scope.tempArray.indexOf(sent_id) < 0) {
        $scope.tempArray.push(sent_id);
        console.log($scope.tempArray);

            for (var i = 0; i < arraytosearch.length; i++) {
                if (arraytosearch[i]['id'] == sent_id) {
                    doesNotExist = false;
                    console.log(sent_id + " IS EXCLUDED");
                } 
            } 
    }
```

Then the last part returns the value for the checkbox and here is the problem. I cannot get a return of true or false from the doesNotExist variable. I noticed that when I take
`for (var i = 0; i < arraytosearch.length; i++) {" ecc...`
out of the if statement everything works...

```
    return doesNotExist; 
    console.log(doesNotExist);
};
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: *"Then the last part returns the value for the checkbox and here is the problem. I cannot get a return of true or false from the doesNotExist variable."* It's unclear what you mean by this. You're clearly setting `doesNotExist` to `true`, and then in response to certain conditions setting it to `false`, and if I piece together your code blocks it looks like you're returning it. So the function will definitely return `true` or `false`. (It also definitely won't hit that last `console.log` line, if that's what's confusing you.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder correct but it's not happening for some reason but what you mean it won't hit the last log? Am I doing something wrong there?

Comment: @Jason You have a `return` statement before your `console.log()` call. The `console.log()` line will never run.

Comment: Jason: What @Lex said. `function foo() { return; console.log("x"); }` will never log anything, because the `return` exits the function. The same applies to your function: That last line will never execute.

Comment: Lol now I know what you mean guys! Sorry long hours...

Comment: It's strange that the checkbox is not returning based on this value. I placed the log before the return and all works fine... Perhaps I should use ng model on the checkbox first...